# How to print data in readable format using laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

```
  $subordinate=Hierarchy::find(12)->subordinates();
  print_r($subordinate);
  return view('goal.create')->with('data',$subordinate);
```

it prints lot of data as like follow:
[image]

this is really horrible. is there anyway to see the exact data fetched from database. I am talking about formatting the array. I used `pre` tag or dd() and getting the following horrible tree of data:
[image]

I can't find the actual data I am looking for.

Comment: Try using `dd($subordinate)` it will be the same thing but easier to navigate

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the actual `QueryBuilder` instance data. If you want to see the database data you need to first retrieve it:

```php
$subordinate=Hierarchy::find(12)->subordinates()->get();
dd($subordinate);
```

if you want it less verbose than that still you can use `toArray`:

```php
$subordinate=Hierarchy::find(12)->subordinates()->get();
dd($subordinate->toArray());
```